# What about reviewing in a mobile device?

Tags: feature-request, support, review, mobile-web

I mostly use my mobile device to go on Stack Overflow as it uses less internet data, but when I want to review something it's not easy as it's only available in full site view. Can there please also be a feature for mobile reviewing?

Comment: I dunno... I think the whole interface really needs to be there for that. People often don't spend enough effort looking at all the important info when reviewing, already.

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn I usually do review through mobile in full site mode, that works perfect till now. So why can't

Comment: @Bala "In full site mode". Yes; a mobile view would show less information. That would be bad.

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn but a mobile view could strip off unnecessary styling, fixed elements, footer, use the mobile topbar, get rid of the review count (badge progress bar). There's a lot that can be made easier for mobile users *without* hiding information relevant to the review.

Comment: @3ventic It could definitely do that, yes. My concern would be that it would be difficult to include the pertinent information in a mobile view. I've also debated making a similar request for the Moderator queue, but... I dunno. Just a doubt I have :)